# How to check what is causing CPU bottleneck on Azure

Tags: azure

I can't find what is causing CPU increase to 100% daily at some periodical time. Is there any way like if you have VM, task manager in Azure dashboard?

I have telemetries:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remote debug your Azure app with Visual Studio : 
When you enable remote debugging on an Azure virtual machine, Azure installs the remote debugging extension on the virtual machine. Then, you can attach to processes on the virtual machine and debug as you normally would.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines/#debugging-azure-virtual-machines

Also to try to understand what happened in the past: if you have activated Azure Diagnostics, you get the output logs in a Azure Storage that you configured for diagnostics. You can have a look at there to try to find what caused the problem.
You can integrate app logs to azure logs to get more accurate or specific info.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-dotnet-diagnostics/

You can also use 3rd party logs like log4net, ... (see appropriate extension or nuget packages).